# How does tf.function compile a python function with autograph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How does `tf.function` compile a python function operating on tensors into a graph, especially wrt autograph? The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) don't go into detail

> `tf.function` constructs a callable that executes a TensorFlow graph (`tf.Graph`) created by trace-compiling the TensorFlow operations in `func`, effectively executing `func` as a TensorFlow graph.

Does it use the special methods called by conditionals (`__bool__`) and loops (`__iter__`) to 'trace' the function's implementation? For example

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def op(t: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    if tf.reduce_sum(t) == 0:
        for _ in t:
            ...
```

could use the fact that the `if` results in `Tensor.__bool__(...)` and `for _ in t` results in `Tensor.__iter__(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - it's more complicated than that. `autograph` is an entire "subpackage" on its own, so a lot happens under the hood when you call `@tf.function`. A nice place to start might be here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference. You could also dive right into the code if you're really curious.